# Make Diodon use the Faenza-Darkest icon in the top panel

Tags: 12.04, panel, icon-themes

The Diodon icon in my panel has a yellow colored fish that does not go well with the other icons. I have tried to follow this post to change the icon:
[How can I change which icon an applet uses?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39336/how-can-i-change-which-icon-an-applet-uses)

... but it only changes the icon in the launcher, not in the panel.

**How can I make diodon use this icon from Faenza-Darkest?**

```
/usr/share/icons/Faenza-Darkest/actions/22/gtk-paste.png
```

my panel looks like this:

[image: My panel with cool, but not-fitting yellow fish in it]

as you can see, while the fish is cool, it does not go well with the other icons.

*I do get a different icon if I change to ubuntu-mono-dark, but as I prefer faenza darkest this is not an option for me.*

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too when installing diodon this morning. I am using Faenza set too. In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

This solution worked for me.

**Create '.icons' directory on your home dir**

```
username@hostname:~$ cd
username@hostname:~$ mkdir -p .icons/Faenza/status/22
```

**Now copy the 'edit-paste' icon from 'Faenza-Darkest' icon set**

```
username@hostname:~$ cp /usr/share/icons/Faenza-Darkest/actions/22/edit-paste.png ~/.icons/Faenza/status/22/diodon-panel.png
```

Now the diodon applet will use Faenza's edit-paste icon.